# getElementsByTagName() equivalent for textNodes

Tags: javascript, dom, dhtml, textnode

Is there any way to get the collection of all `textNode` objects within a document?

`getElementsByTagName()` works great for Elements, but `textNode`s are not Elements.

**Update:** I realize this can be accomplished by walking the DOM - as many below suggest. I know how to write a DOM-walker function that looks at every node in the document. I was hoping there was some browser-native way to do it. After all it's a little strange that I can get all the `<input>`s with a single built-in call, but not all `textNode`s.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

**Update**:

I have outlined some basic performance tests for each of these 6 methods over 1000 runs. `getElementsByTagName` is the fastest but it does a half-assed job, as it does not select all elements, but only one particular type of tag ( i think `p`) and blindly assumes that its firstChild is a text element. It might be little flawed but its there for demonstration purpose and comparing its performance to `TreeWalker`. [Run the tests yourselves on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaqtg/10/) to see the results.

1. Using a TreeWalker
2. Custom Iterative Traversal
3. Custom Recursive Traversal
4. Xpath query
5. querySelectorAll
6. getElementsByTagName

Let's assume for a moment that there is a method that allows you to get all `Text` nodes natively. You would still have to traverse each resulting text node and call `node.nodeValue` to get the actual text as you would do with any DOM Node. So the issue of performance is not with iterating through text nodes, but iterating through all nodes that are not text and checking their type. I would argue (based on the results) that `TreeWalker` performs just as fast as `getElementsByTagName`, if not faster (even with getElementsByTagName playing handicapped).

```
Ran each test 1000 times.

Method                  Total ms        Average ms
--------------------------------------------------
document.TreeWalker          301            0.301
Iterative Traverser          769            0.769
Recursive Traverser         7352            7.352
XPath query                 1849            1.849
querySelectorAll            1725            1.725
getElementsByTagName         212            0.212
```

---

Source for each method:

**TreeWalker**

```
function nativeTreeWalker() {
    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        document.body, 
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, 
        null, 
        false
    );

    var node;
    var textNodes = [];

    while(node = walker.nextNode()) {
        textNodes.push(node.nodeValue);
    }
}
```

**Recursive Tree Traversal**

```
function customRecursiveTreeWalker() {
    var result = [];

    (function findTextNodes(current) {
        for(var i = 0; i < current.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var child = current.childNodes[i];
            if(child.nodeType == 3) {
                result.push(child.nodeValue);
            }
            else {
                findTextNodes(child);
            }
        }
    })(document.body);
}
```

**Iterative Tree Traversal**

```
function customIterativeTreeWalker() {
    var result = [];
    var root = document.body;

    var node = root.childNodes[0];
    while(node != null) {
        if(node.nodeType == 3) { /* Fixed a bug here. Thanks @theazureshadow */
            result.push(node.nodeValue);
        }

        if(node.hasChildNodes()) {
            node = node.firstChild;
        }
        else {
            while(node.nextSibling == null && node != root) {
                node = node.parentNode;
            }
            node = node.nextSibling;
        }
    }
}
```

**querySelectorAll**

```
function nativeSelector() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("body, body *"); /* Fixed a bug here. Thanks @theazureshadow */
    var results = [];
    var child;
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        child = elements[i].childNodes[0];
        if(elements[i].hasChildNodes() && child.nodeType == 3) {
            results.push(child.nodeValue);
        }
    }
}
```

**getElementsByTagName** (handicap)

```
function getElementsByTagName() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var results = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        results.push(elements[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
}
```

**XPath**

```
function xpathSelector() {
    var xpathResult = document.evaluate(
        "//*/text()", 
        document, 
        null, 
        XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, 
        null
    );

    var results = [], res;
    while(res = xpathResult.iterateNext()) {
        results.push(res.nodeValue);  /* Fixed a bug here. Thanks @theazureshadow */
    }
}
```

Also, you might find this discussion helpful - http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/153239-how-do-i-get-elements-text-node

Comment: I have gotten mixed results for each of the methods above in different browser - these results above are for Chrome. Firefox and Safari behave very differently. I don't have have access to IE unfortunately, but you could test these yourselves on IE to see if it works. As for browser optimization, I wouldn't worry about picking a different method for each browser as long as the differences are in order of tens of milliseconds or maybe even the low hundreds.

Comment: This is a really useful answer, but beware that the different methods return very different things. Many of them only get text nodes if they're the first child of their parent. Some of them can only get the text, while others can return actual text nodes with minor modifications.

There is an error in Iterative Tree Traversal that may affect its performance. Change `node.nodeType = 3` to `node.nodeType == 3`

Comment: @theazureshadow - thanks for pointing out the glaring `=` bug. I've fixed that, and the xpath version was simply returning `Text` objects, and not the actual string contained in it like the other methods were doing. The method that is only getting the text of the first child is intentionally wrong, and I've mentioned that in the beginning. I will re-run the tests, and post the updated results here. All tests (except getElementsByTagName and xpath) are returning the same number of text nodes. XPath is reporting about 20 more nodes than the others which I'll ignore for now.

Comment: The query selector method will also report a slightly different number of text nodes, as `querySelector` cannot query by text nodes. A query like `body *` will find only descendant elements (not text nodes) within the body element.

Comment: @Anurag: Yeah, you'd have to go through all the elements and get each of their text nodes. It should also go through the body element's text nodes. Change to `querySelectorAll('body, body *')`

Comment: IE 9+ supports TreeWalkers... =\
[MDN - createTreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createTreeWalker)

Comment: I've made the tests equivalent and made a jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/text-node-traversal

Comment: Nice work @TimDown - that handicapped test was an eye-sore for a long time :) You should add it as an answer..

Comment: Pushing all nodes into an array is something you will certainly avoid in performance critical code, so I removed this very expensive calls by simply counting the nodes. createTreeWalker comes out first now: http://jsperf.com/text-node-traversal/5 . The numbers differ in the 3 cases (limited scope of test cases), so the results differ!

Comment: About XPath `//*/text()`, why not `//text()`?  Is the real translation of "all textNode objects within a document".

Comment: NodeFilter not supported in IE making the tree walker performance dubious at best: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTreeWalker

Comment: OMG I had no idea about `document.createTreeWalker` - look like a fantastic method! Also your custom iterative walker is an eye opener - so much more efficient and actually easier to read/understand than the usual stand-in recursive version!

Comment: Is `"//*/text()",` necessary, or would `//text()` also work?

Comment: For Iterative Tree Traversal method above, if the `document.body` has next sibling, e.g., `<script>`, then the traversal will go to `body`'s sibling, and eventually generates `TypeError: node is null`.

Comment: jsfiddle/jsperf links are dead.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a modern `Iterator` version of the fastest TreeWalker method:

```
function getTextNodesIterator(el) { // Returns an iterable TreeWalker
    const walker = document.createTreeWalker(el, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
    walker[Symbol.iterator] = () => ({
        next() {
            const value = walker.nextNode();
            return {value, done: !value};
        }
    });
    return walker;
}
```

Usage:

```
for (const textNode of getTextNodesIterator(document.body)) {
    console.log(textNode)
}
```

## Safer version

Using the iterator directly might get stuck if you move the nodes around while looping. This is safer, it returns an array:

```
function getTextNodes(el) { // Returns an array of Text nodes
    const walker = document.createTreeWalker(el, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
    const nodes = [];
    while (walker.nextNode()) {
        nodes.push(walker.currentNode);
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I know you specifically asked for a collection, but if you just meant that informally and didn't care if they were all joined together into one big string, you can use:

```
var allTextAsString = document.documentElement.textContent || document.documentElement.innerText;
```

...with the first item being the DOM3 standard approach. Note however that `innerText` appears to exclude script or style tag contents in implementations that support it (at least IE and Chrome) while `textContent` includes them (in Firefox and Chrome).

Comment: Thanks - that's not what I wanted though. My needs call for being able to inspect them in-place as DOM objects (like finding their parents, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative that's a bit more idiomatic and (hopefully) easier to understand.

```js
function getText(node) {
    // recurse into each child node
    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        node.childNodes.forEach(getText);
    }
    // get content of each non-empty text node
    else if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        const text = node.textContent.trim();
        if (text) {
            console.log(text); // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

after `createTreeWalker` is deprecated you can use

```js
  /**
   * Get all text nodes under an element
   * @param {!Element} el
   * @return {Array<!Node>}
   */
  function getTextNodes(el) {
    const iterator = document.createNodeIterator(el, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
    const textNodes = [];
    let currentTextNode;
    while ((currentTextNode = iterator.nextNode())) {
      textNodes.push(currentTextNode);
    }
    return textNodes;
  }
```

Comment: Where have you seen createTreeWalker is deprecated?

Comment: `createTreeWalker()` is NOT deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-createtreewalker

Answer (score 1):

```
 document.deepText= function(hoo, fun){
        var A= [], tem;
        if(hoo){
            hoo= hoo.firstChild;
            while(hoo!= null){
                if(hoo.nodeType== 3){
                    if(typeof fun== 'function'){
                        tem= fun(hoo);
                        if(tem!= undefined) A[A.length]= tem;
                    }
                    else A[A.length]= hoo;
                }
                else A= A.concat(document.deepText(hoo, fun));
                hoo= hoo.nextSibling;
            }
        }
        return A;
    }
```

/*
You can return an array of all the descendant text nodes of some parent element,
or you can pass it some function and do something (find or replace or whatever)
to the text in place.

This example returns the text of the non-whitespace textnodes in the body:

```
var A= document.deepText(document.body, function(t){
    var tem= t.data;
    return /\S/.test(tem)? tem: undefined;
});
alert(A.join('\n'))
```

*/

Handy for search and replace, highlighting and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
var el1 = document.childNodes[0]
function get(node,ob)
{
        ob = ob || {};

        if(node.childElementCount)
        {

            ob[node.nodeName] = {}
            ob[node.nodeName]["text"] = [];
            for(var x = 0; x < node.childNodes.length;x++)
            {   
                if(node.childNodes[x].nodeType == 3)
                {
                    var txt = node.childNodes[x].nodeValue;


                    ob[node.nodeName]["text"].push(txt)
                    continue
                }
                get(node.childNodes[x],ob[node.nodeName])       
            };  
        }
        else
        {
            ob[node.nodeName]   = (node.childNodes[0] == undefined ? null :node.childNodes[0].nodeValue )
        }
        return ob
}



var o = get(el1)
console.log(o)
```