# Grab any Text Node within the BODY using Jquery

Tags: jquery, text, nodevalue, dom-node

Hoping someone can help. I need to grab any text node inside the body.  Even if it is NOT contained within any other element.

I've tried:

```
$("p, div, html, body").each(function(){
    $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        var regExText = /(\w|\d|,|;|&)/;                                           
        if (this.nodeType == 3 && regExText.test(this.nodeValue)) {
            $(this).wrap('<span></span>');
            }
      });
});
```

This is grabbing them in the Ps and Divs but not in the body itself.

Comment: Which is the right answer? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is not what you want?

```
$('body').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

`contents()` will only return the children elements of the tags you have specified - p, div, html, and body. A text node inside a td or a h1 tag will not be found for instance.

One way to get all text nodes inside the `<body>` tag using jQuery is to search for children of body and its descendants,

```
$("body, body *").contents().filter(function() {
    // if this is a text node and matches regex
    // then do something to it
}
```

You can find various other non-jQuery approaches to get all text nodes in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes).

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/c25Ta/).  I'd say there's no need to include `html` in your selector though, is there really anything outside of the `<body>` element you want to deal with in a `<span>`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just clean the HTML?

```
var strInputCode=$("body").html();
var strTagStrippedText = strInputCode.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
alert("Output text:\n" + strTagStrippedText);
```

I must admit that probably $("body").text(), does the thing.