# exclude regex on the same part of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Hello i need to colorize some text in the contentEditable div. Let's say i need to highlight `+` with blue color. On keyup event i do following `$textarea.html($textarea.html().replace((/-/))/g,"<span class='blue'>$1</span>")`
The obvious problem that replace fires up on the same part of stirng more than once (because i have keyup event). I can use only that type of event keyup event. How to do this? Thanks

UPD*
Maybe im not clear describe my problem. Im typing '-' and then continute type `- asdasdad`. The problem is keyup event fires after each letter (this is a must), so i get too much spans, because '-' is always in string.

Comment: I don't get the problem. I like your avatar, though.

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331644/regex-to-search-html-return-but-not-actual-html-jquery/5403731#5403731

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because javascript doesn't support lookbehind assertion you can do something like:

```
var str = 'abc-def-xyz';
str = str.replace(/(<span class='blue'>)?-(<\/span>)?/g, function($0,$1,$2){ return $1?$0:"<span class='blue'>-</span>";});
```

**output:**

```
abc<span class='blue'>-</span>def<span class='blue'>-</span>xyz
```

even if you run it multiple times.

Comment: thanks, im on it solution right now, but it looks like hardcode, thought there is more elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could try is a negative lookahead, something like:

```
$textarea.html($textarea.html().replace((/-(?!<\/span>/))/g,"<span class='blue'>$1</span>")
```

That matches any "-" that isn't followed by "</span>". After you have replaced a particular dash once, it shouldn't get replaced on the next keyup. It's a bit of a hack, granted, but I think it satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Sorry, on my iPad in bed, so I didn't create a test case, but I tried the regex in regexpal.com to make sure it would match correctly.

Comment: Oh wait, I didn't escape the forward slash in the regex; that may be the problem. Changed (although still not tested: still in bed!)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier for you to use: http://codemirror.net/ and write a custom mode for your circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to run a certain regex replacement in a jQuery `keyup` event, but only for the first time. You can use `one()` for this, to have the event handler unbind after it is first called.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $textarea = ...

    $('#somewhere').one('keyup', function() {
        $textarea.html($textarea.html().replace('-', "<span class='blue'>-</span>"));
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hans/cJVcf/1/)