# Javascript Condition to Search HTML for String and Return True

Tags: javascript

I'm using a landing page A/B testing tool called Optimizely. One of the targeting methods is by the URL the visitor is on + a custom Javascript condition.  There's a box where I can enter the Javascript condition. I need the condition to search the HTML for the word "checkout" and evaluate to true if found. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: open the code source (press cmd + u or cmd + option + u on mac) and after use the find press (cmd + f on mac)

Comment: So if the word checkout is anywhere are on the page?  Would it be in any of the element "name" attributes, or any other attribute?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can do `$('body').text().toLowerCase().indexOf('checkout') != -1`.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions.  If you are not a programmer, I'd suggest hiring one or starting to learn with a tutorial.  http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/

Answer (score 2):

I used the treewalker code from this post:
[getElementsByTagName() equivalent for textNodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes)

```
function checkoutIsPresent() {
  var result = [];
  var root = document.body;

  var node = root.childNodes[0];
  while (node != null) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) { /* Fixed a bug here. Thanks @theazureshadow */
      result.push(node.nodeValue);
    }

    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
      node = node.firstChild;
    }
    else {
      while (node.nextSibling == null && node != root) {
        node = node.parentNode;
      }
      node = node.nextSibling;
    }
  }

  if (!result) return false;
  for (var i = 0, len = result.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (result[i].indexOf('checkout') > -1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

If can be called like this:

```
if(checkoutIsPresent()){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I'd convert `result[i]` to lowercase just in case the string is capitalized as well.

Comment: Yeah, I actually tested with the toLowerCase() in there at first since my test page contained 'Checkout'.  Great point.

Comment: @Blender: myself personally, I like your jQuery solution.  I tried to provide a pure javascript just in case it wasn't available, but yours is very elegant (as jQuery often is).

Comment: jQuery is *really* nice for things like this. I can't do much without it anymore...