# How can I get all "p" except <p> tags -javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to replace all "p" with x.

```
var re = new RegExp("p","g");
    document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace(re, "x");
```

But this code line replaces all "p" letters and paragraph tags with x.

Before:

```
p and <p>
```

After:

```
x and <x>
```

How can I replace only p letters (not a tag)?

Comment: Safest way would be iterating over the text nodes only and replace their contents.

Comment: What about scripts? `alert("I am a paragraph")` will become `alert("I am a xaragraxh")`.

Comment: @Mathijs Flietstra thank you.. but it replaces all tags that contain "p" except paragprah.. like <inPut>..

Comment: `<pre>..</pre>`, `<span style="display:inline-block"></span>`, `<div class="post"` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the great answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2579666/447356), you can grab all text nodes in the document with such a code, then iterate over them and change their value:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        document.body, 
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, 
        null, 
        false
    );

    var node;
    var textNodes = [];

    while(node = walker.nextNode()) {
        textNodes.push(node);
    }

    var regex = new RegExp("p","g");
    for (var i = 0; i < textNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = textNodes[i];
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(regex, "x");
    }
};
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/NHPvM/).

From what I've seen, it's supported by all modern browsers and even IE9.

Answer (score 2):

Try **exact match** in `regex`.

```
var re = new RegExp(/^p$/,"g")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var re = new RegExp(/(?<!<)p(?!>)/,"g");
```

beware of `</p>`

also, if you want to consider all `<p class...` tags, you should use more complicated regex.