# TreeWalker does not traverse <iframe> documents

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I'm writing a script to retrieve text nodes (and other related elements) from an HTML document. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2579869/1149773), I was using the following. (The definition for the `acceptTextNode` function is omitted for simplicity.)

```
var textNodes = [];

var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    rootNode,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL,
    { acceptNode: acceptTextNode });

while (treeWalker.nextNode())
    textNodes.push(treeWalker.currentNode);
```

However, I discovered that this approach fails when the document contains other documents nested within `<iframe>` elements, such as for the "Compose" facility in Outlook.com. (Assume that the domains of the `<iframe>` documents as the same as the parent document.)

I managed to work around the issue by retrieving the descendent documents manually, using `getElementsByTagName`:

```
var textNodes = [];
var rootNodes = [ rootNode ];

for (var i = 0; i < rootNodes.length; i++)
{
    if (rootNodes[i].getElementsByTagName)
    {
        var childFrames = rootNodes[i].getElementsByTagName("iframe");
        for (var j = 0; j < childFrames.length; j++)
            if (childFrames[j].contentDocument)
                rootNodes.push(childFrames[j].contentDocument);
    }
}


for (var i = 0; i < rootNodes.length; i++)
{
    var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
        rootNodes[i],
        NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL,
        { acceptNode: acceptTextNode });

    while (treeWalker.nextNode())
        textNodes.push(treeWalker.currentNode);
}
```

However, this feels like a hack, since it's combining manual traversal with the built-in `TreeWalker`. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Iframes are sandboxed, so this is supposed to happen. That's not an answer to your question, but just an FYI on why this happens

Comment: @Joeytje50: I can understand the rationale you provide. On the other hand, I'm not sure I agree that it should apply for same-domain documents. `<iframe>` elements are commonly (ab)used as a way of structuring the visual layout of a page (like in Outlook.com). A developer seeking to get all the text nodes (or other category of nodes) for a page would typically want to traverse the `<iframe>` documents too.

Comment: `<iframe>` is usually used to display documents from a different domain; if it's from the same domain, you can simply load the data it with AJAX and integrate them into the same page. But I guess an option in `treeWalker` would be nice to filter which elements it should take into account / ignore.

Comment: True, but fact remains that all iframes are strictly isolated from the rest of the page, for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use this for your iframes or similar

```
window.frames[0].document.createTreeWalker(
        window.frames[0].document.body
```

for the creation tree, with iframe.

like this

```
 var treeWalker =  window.frames[0].document.createTreeWalker(
    window.frames[0].document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL,
    { acceptNode: acceptTextNode });
```

In the iframes.