# More Efficiently replace escaped unicode characters on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, prototypejs

I have a page which includes escaped Unicode characters. (For example the characters 漢字 are escaped as \u6F22\u5B57). [This page shows how you can use the unescape() method to convert the escaped \u6F22\u5B57 to 漢字.](http://escape.online-toolz.com/tools/javascript-escape-functions.php)  I have a method that converts all of the Unicode escaped characters, but it is not very fast.

```
function DecodeAllUnicodeCharacters (strID)
{
    var strstr = $(strID).innerHTML;
    var arrEncodeChars = strstr.match(/\\u[0-9A-Z]{4,6}/g);
    for (var ii = 0; ii < arrEncodeChars.length; ii++) {
        var sUnescaped = eval("unescape('"+arrEncodeChars[ii]+"')");
        strstr = strstr.replace(arrEncodeChars[ii], sUnescaped);
    }
    $(strID).innerHTML = strstr;
}
```

The part that takes longest is setting the innerHTML here: $(strID).innerHTML = strstr;
Is there a good way to replace the characters without redoing the innerHTML of the whole page?

Comment: I don't think this should need to be done on the client side.

Comment: I really wish I could do this on the server side.  I really do.  But if I want to send the characters unencoded, then I need to replace all of the strings in the code with more modern strings.  And that re-write will probably take a year.  My boss is not going to accept that, so I have to add a javascript hack.

Comment: What do you mean, "modern strings"? Shouldn't it be possible to do that rewrite programmatically?

Comment: By modern strings I mean something like std::string which can handle 32 bit unicode characters. I may be exaggerating by saying a year, but our codebase is a 10+ year mess of string casts into and out of string-like objects that only our company uses.  This is not the sort of things that I could just ctrl+R replace.

Comment: Another reason is that I will probably have to change a bunch of company libraries, and I am going to have a hard time telling everyone else that they need to change their code just because I want to make my job easier.  I think I'm stuck with making the change in JavaScript.

Comment: OK, I see. But shouldn't it still be possible to do the escaping in the output methods (where you generate web responses, ie. HTML/JS/CSS/JSON etc) of your server, so that the pages are server with the correct content-type

Comment: Sometimes I can, so I already do that, but sometimes I can't due to the templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is slow to set `innerHTML` is because that causes the browser to parse it as HTML, and if there are child elements they get recreated which is extra slow.  Instead we need to find just the [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) and selectively treat them if they contain escaped content.  I base the following on [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2579869/471559) and demonstrated [in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwbco8s1/1/).

```
Element.addMethods({
    // element is Prototype-extended HTMLElement
    // nodeType is a Node.* constant
    // callback is a function where first argument is a Node
    forEachDescendant: function (element, nodeType, callback)
    {
        element = $(element);
        if (!element) return;
        var node = element.firstChild;
        while (node != null) {
            if (node.nodeType == nodeType) {
                callback(node);
            }

            if(node.hasChildNodes()) {
                node = node.firstChild;
            }
            else {
                while(node.nextSibling == null && node.parentNode != element) {
                    node = node.parentNode;
                }
                node = node.nextSibling;
            }
        }
    },
    decodeUnicode: function (element)
    {
        var regex = /\\u([0-9A-Z]{4,6})/g;
        Element.forEachDescendant(element, Node.TEXT_NODE, function(node) {
            // regex.test fails faster than regex.exec for non-matching nodes
            if (regex.test(node.data)) {
                // only update when necessary
                node.data = node.data.replace(regex, function(_, code) {
                    // code is hexidecimal captured from regex
                    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(code, 16));
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The benefit of [`element.addMethods`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/addMethods/), aside from aesthetics, is the functional pattern.  You can use `decodeUnicode` several ways:

```
// single element
$('element_id').decodeUnicode();
// or
Element.decodeUnicode('element_id');

// multiple elements
$$('p').each(Element.decodeUnicode);
// or
$$('p').invoke('decodeUnicode');
```

Comment: I deliberately wrote my own decode method instead of `unescape` because (1) `unescape` is deprecated (2) it only works in `eval` and `eval` is slow and dangerous (3) it wasn't complicated.

Comment: I just realised that [`unescape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) has no effect in the original question since it only works for URL encodings.  It appeared to work because the use of `eval` put data into a [JS string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) which uses \uXXXX style encoding.  You could get the same effect with just `eval("'"+arrEncodeChars[ii]+"'")`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted ?

```
function DecodeAllUnicodeCharacters(id) {
    $(id).innerHTML = decodeURI($(id).innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: No.  You see I only want to decode the \uXXXX characters.  If you run decodeURI() over html elements, then it malforms the html elements.  So it is pretty essential that I only run unecode() on the characters that I want to change, rather than the entire page.  Also, $(id).innerHTML = decodeURI($(id).innerHTML; runs at about the same speed as the code above, because most of the time is taken by $(id).innerHTML = "the html for the page".