# Is text inside a <script> or <style> considered a textnode?

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

I'm using one of the treewalkers from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2579869/82548 to modify textnodes in an HTML document via RegEx's, but I'm worried it'll modify inline scripts or styles. Do I need to take extra precaution to ignore these tags, or does the browser do this for me?

And before you say anything about it being a bad idea to modify text this way, it's in a userscript for personal use.

Comment: They are textnodes. Also, nobody will complain if you use regexp on textnodes; people will warn you about using regexp on unparsed HTML/XML.

Comment: Easiest way to find out is to test the childnodes [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) is 3

Comment: You could even remove the script tags. By the time you start manipulating the dom they will have already been compiled and are no longer doing anything important