# Using a TreeWalker to retrieve non-Javascript text nodes

Tags: javascript, dom, dhtml, textnode

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes) teaches how to get all TextNodes inside the document, and this is getting me the Javascript texts as well. What is the best way to filter out all the Nodes that are Javascript code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Text inside `<script>` tags has only one thing in common: their parent is a `<script>` element.

```
if (node.parentNode.nodeName !== 'SCRIPT')
```

Another approach is to use the filter:

```js
var rejectScriptTextFilter = {
  acceptNode: function(node) {
    if (node.parentNode.nodeName !== 'SCRIPT') {
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }
  }
};

var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
  document.body, 
  NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, 
  rejectScriptTextFilter,
  false
);

var node;
var textNodes = [];

while(node = walker.nextNode()) {
  textNodes.push(node.nodeValue);
}

console.log(textNodes);
```

```html
<script> var str = "script here"; </script>
<p> text here </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could clone the original `document`, remove `<script>` elements at cloned `document`, then iterate remaining nodes of cloned `document`