# Vanilla JS: Find all the DOM elements that just contain text

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to get all the DOM elements in an HTML that doesn't contain any node, but text only.

I've got this code right now:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("body *");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if(!elements[i].hasChildNodes()) {
        console.log(elements[i])
    }
}
```

This prints of course elements that have absolutely no content (and curiously enough, iframes).
Texts are accounted as a child node, so the `.childNodes.length` equals 1, but I don't know how to distinguish the nodes from the text. `typeof` the first node is always object, sadly.

How to distinguish the texts from the nodes?

Comment: Do you want nodeType? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes

Comment: @Pavlo: That's not a duplicate.

Comment: @clockwork The function he is looking for is on the page `function nativeSelector() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("body, body *"); 
    var results = [];
    var child;
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        child = elements[i].childNodes[0];
        if(elements[i].hasChildNodes() && child.nodeType == 3) {
            results.push(child.nodeValue);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @Pavlo: That function doesn't do what he's asking. As I said, it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are looking for leaf nodes of DOM with something inside the **textContent** property of the leaf node.

Let's traverse DOM and work out our little logic on leaf nodes.

```
const nodeQueue = [ document.querySelector('html') ];    
const textOnlyNodes = [];
const textRegEx = /\w+/gi;

function traverseDOM () {
  let currentNode = nodeQueue.shift();

  // Our Leaf node
  if (!currentNode.childElementCount && textRegEx.test(currentNode.textContent)) {
    textOnlyNodes.push(currentNode);
    return;
  }

  // Nodes with child nodes
  nodeQueue.push(...currentNode.children);
  traverseDOM();
}
```

**childElementCount** property make sure that the node is the leaf node and the RegEx test on **textContent** property is just my understanding of what a text implies in general. You can anytime tune the expression to make it a btter fit for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for elements that have no `.firstElementChild`, which means it will only have text (or other invisible stuff).

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("body *");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (!elements[i].firstElementChild) {
    console.log(elements[i].nodeName)
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  text and elements <span>text only</span>
</p>

<div>text only</div>
```

The `script` that the stack snippet is included because it also only has text. You can filter out scripts if needed. This will also include elements that can not have content, like `<input>`.