# Search entire DOM for number

Tags: javascript

I need to search my entire document for a phone number, and compile a list of elements which have this phone number in them.

However I have encountered afew snags.

1. I can't simply do `document.body.innerHTML` and replace the numbers, as this messes up third party scripts.
2. The following will match the elements, but ONLY if they have the number within them, and nothing else:

   ```
   let elements = document.querySelectorAll("a, div, p, li");
   let found = [];
   for (let elm in elements) {
       if (elements.hasOwnProperty(elm)) {
           if (elements[elm].textContent !== undefined && elements[elm].textContent.search("00000 000000") != -1) {
               found.push(elements[elm]);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   So the following element will not match:

   ```
   <li class="footer__telephone">
       <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>00000 000000
   </li>
   ```

   Due to having the `i` tag in there.
3. Using `textContent` instead of `text` also does not work as the parent of an element will then match, but I don't want the parent.

**Edit:**

```
<div class="row-block hmpg-text">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">


            <div class="twelvecol">
                00000 000000
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Lets say the above is my HTML, if I loop through all the elements and test them with `testContent` then the first is going to be returned as true, to containing my number, but I need the element with the class of `twelvecol` on it, not the parent which is 4 levels up.

Comment: Use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes) to obtain all text nodes that match your string, then return each text node's parent element.

Comment: In the example you provided, you will get `li.footer__telephone` as your found element. This is indeed the container of your phone number. What exactly are you trying to find?

Comment: you can `document.querySelectorAll("*")`

Comment: @samu this will also get the main `wrapper` as running this through textContent will display ALL the website text.

Comment: @MartynBall You can always just check just 1 level of textContent, so you will find only related containers.

Comment: @dfsq this won't work, see updated post.

Comment: Yes, it will, you just need to check first level textContent's as I said in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find an answer, similar to what Phylogenesis said however couldn't get any of them examples working.

```
function replaceText(el, regex_display, regex_link) {

    // Replace any links
    if (el.tagName === "A") {
        if (regex_link.test(el.getAttribute("href"))) {
            el.setAttribute("href", el.getAttribute("href").replace(regex_link, replacement.replace(/\s/g, '')));
        }
    }
    if (el.nodeType === 3) {
        if (regex_display.test(el.data)) el.data = el.data.replace(regex_display, replacement);
        if (regex_link.test(el.data)) el.data = el.data.replace(regex_link, replacement);
    } else {
        let children = el.childNodes;
        for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            replaceText(children[i], regex_display, regex_link);
        }
    }
}

let bodyChildren = document.body.childNodes;

let search_display = new RegExp(search, "g");
let search_link = new RegExp(search.replace(/\s/g, ''), "g");

for (let i = 0; i < bodyChildren.length; i++) {
    replaceText(bodyChildren[i], search_display, search_link);
}
```