# highlight max 6 word from gmail messages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail

The use case of my extension is when the user opens up the Gmail, fire an API call and fetch the list of topics(the topics can be more than 500). Then when the user opens up the message, if from that fetched topics any max 6 words match with the word in the opened message, it should be highlighted.

**For example**

If the fetched topic has following topics

```
topics: {
  hello: 10,
  how: 1,
  mandy: 12,
  google: 90,
  extension: 13,
  local: 20
}
```

And I have a Gmail message as following

```
hello, my name is mandy. I work at google.
```

then the word `hello`, `mandy` and `google` should get highlighted because, those word from the message matched with the topics object.

For now, I could fetch the topic object and pass that topic object to the function searchPage but does not know the way to match.

Here is what I have done till now

```
function fetchTopics() {
    const apiUrl = `https://baseurl.ngrok.io/useful_topics`;
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['user_token'], function(result) {
        const decoded = JSON.parse(atob(result.user_token));
        const access_token = decoded['access-token'];
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Access-Token', access_token);
        fetch(apiUrl, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers
        })
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                searchPage(data);
                // for (var key in data) {
                //  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                //      searchPage(key);
                //  }
                // }
            });
    });
}


function searchPage(topicObj) {
  console.log('topicObj', topicObj);
  // read all the words in the currently opened gmail messages and highlight any max 
  // 6 words in the message if there is a match 
}
```

I will have topicObj in following format(hashmap structure)

```
topics: {
  hostname: 4,
  cto: 19,
  maharjan: 45,
  aws: 382,
  axosoft: 66,
  its: 26,
  repo: 15,
  anurag: 585,
  unsubscribe: 65,
  bitbucket: 313,
  having: 28,
  devops: 414,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can split the message text into an array and then compare the array entries with your list of keywords using a loop.

```
var array = msg.split(" ");
```

*this is how to split your msg text into an array

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

  var x;
  for (i = 0; x < keys.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] == keys[x])
     //match
   } 

  }
```

*this is how to do the comparison

Comment: maybe check the DOM to see if there is any class or id for the message body..
`var text = document.getElementById('msgBody').textContent;`

Comment: Is treewalker efficient enough for crawling the message?

Comment: it is actually..
check the first comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes

Comment: treewalker crawls whole document not just the currently opened message, i guess.

Comment: 'user opens up the message'
at the point, the document is the message div plus other divs.. but it should be detectable..