# Problem with jQuery contains method selecting div and span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have problem facing selecting `div`/`span` elements via jQuery `contains(arg)` method. I want to count the total number of elements that contain specific text. But it is giving different results to different HTML elelemts. See the code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  $("#co").text($("span:contains('cool')").length)
  $("#co1").text($("div:contains('cool')").length)
  $("#co2").text($("li:contains('cool')").length)
  $("#co3").text($("p:contains('cool')").length)
});
```

```html
Span -<span id="co"> </span>
<div></div>
Div -<span id="co1"> </span>
<div></div>
Li -<span id="co2"> </span>
<div></div>
p -<span id="co3"> </span>
<br><br>

<div> <div> cool </div> </div>
<p> <p> cool </p> </p>
<ul><li> <li> cool </li> </li></ul>
<span> <span> cool </span> </span>
```

The above code outputs result

```
Span -2
Div -2
Li -1 
p -1
```

I just don't understand WHY, while every element should have same count.

Comment: Parts of your HTML are invalid. E.g. you can't nest `<li>` or `<p>`elements

Answer (score 2):

To understand why, look at the *rendered HTML*. When you have a `<p>` inside another unclosed `<p>`, the browser things you meant to *end* the previous `<p>` and start a new one, because `<p>`s cannot nest. Similarly, a `<li>` cannot exist directly inside another `<li>` - it may only exist as a child of a `<ul>` (or `<ol>`), so `<li> <li> cool </li> </li>` gets interpreted as `<li> </li><li> cool </li>`.

On the other hand, `<span>`s and `<div>`s *can* be nested in each other, so they appear in the document the same way your HTML is written.

```js
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div> <div> cool </div> </div>
<p> <p> cool </p> </p>
<ul><li> <li> cool </li> </li></ul>
<span> <span> cool </span> </span>
```

So, the rendered document has:

- `<span> <span> cool </span> </span>` - a `cool` nested inside 2 `<span>`s
- `<p> </p><p> cool </p> <p></p>` - a `cool` nested inside *one* `<p>` (the other `<p>`s being empty)
- `<ul><li> </li><li> cool </li> </ul>` - a `cool` nested inside *one* `<li>` (the other `<li>`s being empty)
- `<div> <div> cool </div> </div>` - a `cool` nested inside 2 `<div>`s

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have another query btw. Element like DIV `<div> <div>cool</div </div>` should show only one result for cool. while it is selecting all the top way of hierarchy. Suppose i have 20 DIVS nested and deepest one contains letter `cool`. Its go on selecting all the 20 DIVS while the result should be 1

Comment: No, you have two `div`s whose `textContent` contains `cool` there. If you want only the innermost elements which have such a text node, I'd [gather all text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes), filter by the ones which contain the text you're looking for, then map to their parent elements.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your jQuery outputs unexpected counts of each element is that your HTML is invalid. When you have invalid HTML, the browser automatically tries to correct it for you, by moving / removing sections that it knows is invalid. If you look at the DOM, you'll see that several of your elements don't exist.

For example, `<p> <p> cool </p> </p>` produces the following during rendering:

[image: p]

In the above, you can see that indeed, only one `<p>` element contains `cool`, resulting in one match.

Fixing up the invalid HTML also displays the correct results:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#co").text($("span:contains('cool')").length)
  $("#co1").text($("div:contains('cool')").length)
  $("#co2").text($("li:contains('cool')").length)
  $("#co3").text($("p:contains('cool')").length)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Span -<span id="co"> </span>
<div></div>
Div -<span id="co1"> </span>
<div></div>
Li -<span id="co2"> </span>
<div></div>
p -<span id="co3"> </span>
<br><br>

<div>
  <div>cool</div>
</div>
<p>cool</p>
<ul>
  <li>cool</li>
</ul>
<span>cool</span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have another query btw.   Element like DIV `<div> <div>cool</div </div>` should show only one result for `cool`. while it is selecting all the top way of hierarchy. Suppose i have 20 DIVS nested and deepest  one contains letter `cool`. Its go on selecting all the 20 DIVS while the result should be 1.