# How to Update All Instances of a String in the Visible Text of a Webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to add a registered trademark symbol to all references to a brand, let's call it "SomeBrand" on a client site. Currently I have this:

```
function updateSomeBrand(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for(el in elements){
    if(["SCRIPT", "META", "HEAD", "STYLE", "IFRAME", "NOSCRIPT", "IMG"].indexOf(elements[el].tagName) < 0){
      if(elements[el].innerText != undefined && elements[el].innerText.indexOf("SomeBrand") > 0){
        console.log(elements[el].innerText);
        console.log(elements[el].innerText.indexOf("SomeBrand"));
        elements[el].innerHTML = elements[el].innerHTML.replace("SomeBrand", "SomeBrand®")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it adds extra ® symbols after all references to SomeBrand, in some cases it adds six or seven. I'm not sure yet why. Is there a better way to go about this? There are a lot of references on different product pages, so I'd like to add some JS to the product page template instead of manually updating them.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `.replace()` in *all* elements, including container elements.  That means that you first replace all of the HTML in the container, then replace it again for each child.

Instead, you should modify text nodes only. [getElementsByTagName() equivalent for textNodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2579666/34397)