# How to display data between double braces in a set of all matches elements without using any library?

Tags: javascript, braces

I want to make a function that can do something like this :

HTML :

```
 <h1 class="demo">I am {{ name }}</h1>
 <span class="demo">{{ name }} learn JavaScript</span>
```

JS :

```
data(".demo", {
   name: "Arc"
};
```

Output :

```
 I am Arc
 Arc learn JavaScript
```

Can the data() function be made which can do this ? I don't want to use any external library for just using this function !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression to replace `{{ .. }}`s in the HTML with the appropriate value in the passed object, if there is one:

```js
const data = (selector, obj) => {
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((elm) => {
    elm.textContent = elm.textContent.replace(
      /{{ *(\w+) *}}/g,
      // If key is in the obj, replace with the value
      // otherwise, replace with the match (make no changes):
      (match, key) => key in obj ? obj[key] : match
    );
  });
};

data(".demo", {
   name: "Arc"
});
```

```html
 <h1 class="demo">I am {{ name }}</h1>
 <span class="demo">{{ name }} learn JavaScript</span>
```

If you also need to take into account nested elements, then select all text nodes of the parent, and do the same thing:

```js
const getTextNodes = (parent) => {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes
    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        parent, 
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, 
        null, 
        false
    );

    var node;
    var textNodes = [];

    while(node = walker.nextNode()) {
        textNodes.push(node);
    }
    return textNodes;
}

const data = (selector, obj) => {
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((elm) => {
    getTextNodes(elm).forEach((node) => {
      node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(
        /{{ *(\w+) *}}/g,
        // If key is in the obj, replace with the value
        // otherwise, replace with the match (make no changes):
        (match, key) => key in obj ? obj[key] : match
      );
    });
  });
};

data(".demo", {
   name: "Arc"
});
```

```css
span > span {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="demo">I am {{ name }}</h1>
 <span class="demo">{{ name }} learn JavaScript <span> nested {{ name }} </span></span>
```

Comment: Assigning to `textContent` on an element like that will wipe out its child elements. To avoid destructive changes, you need to work at the node level, not the element level.

Comment: I have a question how can I then insert Html in place of text ?

Comment: e.g. data(".demo", { name: "<i>Arc</i>" });

Comment: @ArcanadianArc That'd be significantly more complicated. If you don't have nested elements, or if there's nothing attached to the nested elements that needs to be preserved, reassign the `innerHTML` of the container, instead of its `textContent`

Comment: A thing suddenly came in my mind. Can this be done ? e.g. data(".demo", { name: { age: "12" } }); and in HTML <h1 class="demo">{{ name.age }}</h1>

Comment: If no then how can I gain it ?

Comment: @ArcanadianArc Possible, but unwieldly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key