# Replace all words in html without affecting tags

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am looking for a way to replace all instances of `Foo` with `<a>Bar</a>` (a functioning link) in a given website. Ideally without any extra library like jquery.

What I tried:

- `document.body.innerHtml` and similars (`document.getElementByTagName('p)`) won't work with a simple `.replace(/Foo/g, '<a>Bar</a>')` because it may end up replacing a `Foo` class-name or id, so it breaks the page. Also may affect some js scripts in the body.
- Editing only textNodes (with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes)) does not work because it displays the `a` tags as text, instead of creating DOM elements.
- Trying to solve the textNodes problem and going to the parent element and applying `.replace` there just generates the same problem as the first bullet.

I've searched for answers to other similar questions but I haven't found any that solves this three points.

Comment: would you like to do it dynamically?

Comment: @Mr. What do you mean by dynamically in this context? The string to be replaced and the replacement should be able to be specified by a function but that can always be done with `new RegExp`.

Comment: there are many ways to do it - on the client side, on the serer side, or pre-processing before you even serve it. which method are you interested?

Comment: @Mr. Client side

Answer (score 2):

You're close, but you need to replace the entire text node with a *set* of three new nodes:

1. a textnode that contains "everything before your string",
2. an HTML node for the tag you want (and don't use `<a>` unless it's an actual link), and then
3. another textnode that contains all the remaining text.

And then, of course, that remaining textnode is now part of the still-unprocessed set of text nodes.

(unless you do a `split` for your term, then interleave as many additional nodes as needed. Then you just run through textnodes one by one without having to put "the remainder" back on your stack)

Comment: Thanks! Could you specify how would you implement point 2? These replacements will happen quite a bit so I am a bit concerned on the efficiency. My first thought is just making single regex (without the 'g' tag) and while-looping until there are no more matches. Was wondering if you knew any 'global' method that does all of these at once (like `.replace` with the 'g' tag).

Comment: "run a regex on what?" Because you can only run regex on strings, and you certainly [can't run it on the body.innerHTML](/a/590789/740553) and expect that to work. So if you want to do it _right_, you'll have to traverse the DOM and use functions like [replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild), [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), and [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). But you're also guaranteed to fail in this for any webpage that uses React or the like.

Comment: (because unlike for a standard web page, where the DOM is the authority, in React etc. the DOM has zero authority, and any UI update will just put the data you replaced right back)