# JavaScript add spaces between sentences while parsing XML string

Tags: javascript, html, xml, string

I have this XML string which I am displaying as a text in a document:

```
<p>The new strain of <s alias="coronavirus">COVID</s>seems to be having a greater spread rate.</p>
```

The following function returns the text form of the XML:

```
function stripHtml(html) {
  // Create a new div element
  var temporalDivElement = document.createElement("div");
  // Set the HTML content with the providen
  temporalDivElement.innerHTML = html;
  // Retrieve the text property of the element (cross-browser support)
  return temporalDivElement.textContent || temporalDivElement.innerText || "";
}
```

The problem is, this function returns the following string:

`The new strain of COVIDseems to be having a greater spread rate.`

which is nearly what I want, but there is no space between the word `COVID` and `seems`. Is it possible that I can add a space between contents of two tags **if it doesn't exist**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to [iterate over text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2579869) and insert spaces at the beginning if they don't exist, something like:

```js
const getTextNodes = (parent) => {
    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        parent,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, 
        null, 
        false
    );

    var node;
    var textNodes = [];

    while(node = walker.nextNode()) {
        textNodes.push(node);
    }
    return textNodes;
}


function stripHtml(html) {
  // Create a new div element
  var temporalDivElement = document.createElement("div");
  // Set the HTML content with the providen
  temporalDivElement.innerHTML = html;
  // Retrieve the text property of the element (cross-browser support)
  for (const node of getTextNodes(temporalDivElement)) {
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/^(?!\s)/, ' ');
  }
  return temporalDivElement.textContent.replace(/  +/g, ' ').trim();
}

console.log(stripHtml(`<p>The new strain of <s alias="coronavirus">COVID</s>seems to be having a greater spread rate.</p>`));
```