# Clearing div child elements without removing from the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

My goal is, using Jquery or vanilla JS, to clear the *inner text only* of a div and each of its child elements while keeping all elements intact after the fact.  In the example below, the div is `student_profile`.

Answers on SO have recommended the functions `.html('')` and `.text('')` but, as my example shows below, this completely removes the child element from the DOM (my example shows only one function but both actually remove the element).  Is there a function that would remove all of the text from the current div and child divs while keeping the elements themselves intact?

Any advice here would be appreciated!

```js
function cleardiv() {


console.log(document.getElementById("student_name"));
$('#student_profile').html('');
console.log(document.getElementById("student_name"));

     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='student_profile'>
  <h1 id="student_name">Foo Bar</h1>
  <p  id="student_id">123</p>
  <p  id="studen_course">math</p>
  <p  id="last_reported">2021-01-01</p>
</div>

<button onclick="cleardiv()">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to [select all text node descendants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2579869) and `.remove()` them, leaving the actual elements intact:

```js
const getTextDecendants = (parent) => {
  const walker = document.createTreeWalker(
    parent,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    null,
    false
  );
  const nodes = [];
  let node;
  while (node = walker.nextNode()) {
    nodes.push(node);
  }
  return nodes;
}

function cleardiv() {
  for (const child of getTextDecendants($('#student_profile')[0])) {
    child.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='student_profile'>
  <h1 id="student_name">Foo Bar</h1>
  <p id="student_id">123</p>
  <p id="studen_course">math</p>
  <p id="last_reported">2021-01-01</p>
</div>

<button onclick="cleardiv()">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the selector `#student_profile *` to include all the child elements.

```js
function cleardiv() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("student_name"));
  $('#student_profile *').text('');
  console.log(document.getElementById("student_name"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='student_profile'>
  <h1 id="student_name">Foo Bar</h1>
  <p  id="student_id">123</p>
  <p  id="studen_course">math</p>
  <p  id="last_reported">2021-01-01</p>
</div>

<button onclick="cleardiv()">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only direct children you're looking to affect, you can iterate the [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) of the parent element. This will clear both element nodes as well as non-element nodes such as text nodes. Here using the [`NodeList#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method provided by the returned NodeList.

```js
function cleardiv() {
  document.getElementById('student_profile')
    .childNodes
    .forEach((node) => (node.textContent = ''));

  console.log(document.getElementById('student_name'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='student_profile'>
  <h1 id="student_name">Foo Bar</h1>
  <p  id="student_id">123</p>
  <p  id="studen_course">math</p>
  <p  id="last_reported">2021-01-01</p>
</div>

<button onclick="cleardiv()">Clear</button>
```