# Regex to select every text word that is text but not HTML or code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Trying to find all words within a specific tag like all p tags, so that I can apply some regex to it and replace all the words.

For example,

```
<p>the lazy cat went <div>up</div> to the cheery fox</p>
```

You can choose an "all words" regex:

```
/\w+/g
```

You can use a jquery replace. Here's my code that not fully working yet.

```
$("p").html($("p").html().replace(/\w+/g, 'fox'));
```

Now what I need to do is get it to work, so that all the words inside the p tag are replaced with another word. Result:

```
<p>fox fox fox fox <div>fox</div> fox fox fox fox</p>
```

How can I get jquery to replace all individual words that are inside a `p` tag, but not affect any other HTML or code inside it?

Comment: Have you tried using ".text" instead of ".html" ? That way you don't need a regex. https://api.jquery.com/text/ Also you could change the selector and iterate over ".each" object and replace the content one by one, if you want to replace it by element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Retrieve all text nodes instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes), and iterate over them to reassign their content to the replaced string.

```js
const getAllTextNodes = (parent) => {
    const walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        parent,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
        null,
        false
    );
    let node;
    const textNodes = [];
    while(node = walker.nextNode()) {
        textNodes.push(node);
    }
    return textNodes;
};
for (const p of $('p')) {
  for (const textNode of getAllTextNodes(p)) {
    textNode.textContent = textNode.textContent.replace(/\w+/g, 'fox');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>the lazy cat went up to the cheery fox</p>
```

Or ditch jQuery, since it's not really providing any benefit

```js
const getAllTextNodes = (parent) => {
    const walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        parent,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
        null,
        false
    );
    let node;
    const textNodes = [];
    while(node = walker.nextNode()) {
        textNodes.push(node);
    }
    return textNodes;
};
for (const p of document.querySelectorAll('p')) {
  for (const textNode of getAllTextNodes(p)) {
    textNode.textContent = textNode.textContent.replace(/\w+/g, 'fox');
  }
}
```

```html
<p>the lazy cat went up to the cheery fox</p>
```